# Unable to run basic declarative jdbi3 in kotlin in existing java gradle project

Tags: java, kotlin, jdbi, jdbi3

I am new to kotlin, my basic `build.gralde` is as follows in an existing java + gradle project.

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.7.20"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("org.jdbi:jdbi3-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jdbi:jdbi3-kotlin-sqlobject")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
}
```

All kotlin dependancies are using version `1.7.20`.

My super basic kotlin is as follows. I've simple data class Org for holding the row values, a Simple RowMapper. I hit same issue even if i use RowMapper or not.

```
data class Org(val name: String)
class OrgRowMapper: RowMapper<Org> {
    override fun map(rs: ResultSet, ctx: StatementContext): Org {
        return Org(rs.getString("name"))
    }
}

interface OrgDao {
    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM organization")
    @RegisterKotlinMapper(OrgRowMapper::class) // with or without rowMapper
    fun listOrg(): List<Org>
}

fun jdbi(): Jdbi {
    val jdbi = Jdbi.create("jdbc:postgresql://...")
    jdbi.installPlugin(KotlinPlugin())
    jdbi.installPlugin(KotlinSqlObjectPlugin())
    return jdbi
}

fun trySomeOrg(jdbi: Jdbi) {
    val orgDao = jdbi.onDemand<OrgDao>()
    val orgs = orgDao.listOrg()
    println(orgs)
}

fun main() {
    val jdbi = jdbi()
    trySomeOrg(jdbi)
}
```

However list call is throwing `MethodNotFound` exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Map kotlin.collections.MapsKt.createMapBuilder()'
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.Visibilities.<clinit>(Visibilities.kt:56)
```

if I avoid `RegisterRowMapper`, I get hit by

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.jvm.internal.PropertyReference1Impl.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)'
```

I believe this has something to do with kotlin-java lambda extensions. If I lift and shift this code in a brand new kotlin only project in IntelliJ, it works.

**Update:**

It seems like an issue with kotlin-reflect, I tried following

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello World")
    println(A::p.javaGetter) // prints "public final int A.getP()"
    println(A::p.javaField)  // prints "private final int A.p"
}
```

in mix kotlin+java project, this throws.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.jvm.internal.PropertyReference1Impl.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)'
```

However works correctly in kotlin only project.

I verified gradle dependencies, kotlin-reflect:1.7.20 is listed under runtimeClassPath

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)).
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api -> 2.0.3
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.20
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.7.20
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.20 (*)
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core -> 1.2.11
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic -> 1.2.11
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.11
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32 -> 2.0.3
+--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api -> 1.3.2
+--- com.newrelic.logging:logback -> 2.5.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1 -> 2.13.4
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.4
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.4 (c)
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.0 -> 1.2.11
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.0 -> 1.2.11 (*)
|    +--- com.newrelic.telemetry:telemetry-core:0.13.2
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 -> 2.0.3
|    \--- com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api:7.6.0 -> 7.10.0
+--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant -> 0.8.8
|    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.8
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.2
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:9.2
|    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.2
|    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:9.2
|    |    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.2
|    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:9.2
|    |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:9.2 (*)
|    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:9.2 (*)
|    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.8.8
|    |    \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.8 (*)
|    \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.8
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.20
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.20 (*)
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:{strictly 2.0.3} -> 2.0.3 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:{strictly 1.7.20} -> 1.7.20 (c)
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:{strictly 1.2.11} -> 1.2.11 (c)
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:{strictly 1.2.11} -> 1.2.11 (c)
+--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:{strictly 1.3.2} -> 1.3.2 (c)
+--- com.newrelic.logging:logback:{strictly 2.5.0} -> 2.5.0 (c)
+--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:{strictly 0.8.8} -> 0.8.8 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:{strictly 1.7.20} -> 1.7.20 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.7.20} -> 1.7.20 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:{strictly 1.7.20} -> 1.7.20 (c)
+--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:{strictly 0.8.8} -> 0.8.8 (c)
+--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:{strictly 0.8.8} -> 0.8.8 (c)
+--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:{strictly 0.8.8} -> 0.8.8 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:{strictly 1.7.20} -> 1.7.20 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations:{strictly 13.0} -> 13.0 (c)
+--- org.ow2.asm:asm:{strictly 9.2} -> 9.2 (c)
+--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:{strictly 9.2} -> 9.2 (c)
+--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:{strictly 9.2} -> 9.2 (c)
\--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:{strictly 9.2} -> 9.2 (c)
```

Comment: Have you tried downgrading your Kotlin version?

Comment: downgraded to 1.6.20, from 1.7.20, still same issue.

Comment: How about adding explicit versions to the dependencies, e.g. `implementation("org.jdbi:jdbi3-kotlin:3.34.0")`?

Comment: @user3738870 thank you for response, i've tried explicit versioning, added more findings in question, seems like an issue with kotlin-reflect

Comment: Probably it has to do with how the Java project is set up. It would be useful to include the whole gradle script in the question because the problem is most likely there.

Comment: After lot of dependancy scrutiny, I figured out com.newrelic.logging:logback:2.5.0 was breaking the java <-> kotlin reflection, upgrading to 2.6.0 fixed it.

Comment: You can add that as an answer so others can use your solution too